# View total Reputation for each month

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-graph

Is there a way to check total reputation by month. For e.g. If current Reputation is 2000, I want to see following:

Beginning of Year : 1000

- Jan 2014 - 200
- Feb 2014 - 300
- Mar 2014 - 400
- Apr 2014 - 100
- May 2014  - 0

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation Leagues for the rescue! The [Stack Exchange Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) (aka "Top Users") is what you need, as it can also show monthly reputation change, e.g. [January 2014](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-01-01).

You'll always see your own first, regardless of your actual rank, making it easy to see the change.